# Find equal or nearest smaller value from an array

Tags: c#, performance

Let's suppose I have this array *(it is actually 255 long, values up to int.MaxValue)*:

```
int[] lows = {0,9,0,0,5,0,0,8,4,1,3,0,0,0,0};
```

From this array I would like to get index of a value **equal** or **smaller** to my number.

```
number = 7 -> index = 4
number = 2 -> index = 9
number = 8 -> index = 7
number = 9 -> index = 1
```

What would be the fastest way of finding it?

So far I've used linear search, but that turned out to be too inefficient for my need, because even though this array is only 255 long, values will be searched for a few million times.

I would need something equal to *TreeSet.floor(E)* used in java. I wanted to use *Dictionary*, but i don't know if it can find first smaller or equal value like I need.

Comment: Since this is done a few million times, if the array holds constant data and the input numbers are of a constrained range, a cache (possible prebuilt) might also be useful - would be O(1) on a cache hit. The cache would map number -> index, for all numbers within the range. For certain ranges, a Radix/Counting sort algorithm can be constructed to create the mapping.

Comment: There is a TreeSet<T> imple in the .NET library, but it's internal. Interestingly enough, a public Sorted<T> is it's base class.

Comment: What about `0`, is it ignored? Because, in your example when you search for `7`, you do not consider the first smaller number which is the first `0` and skip all the next `0s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the array and then do a binary search to find the values.

See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search

and

[Array.BinarySearch Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y15ef976.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If it's not sorted (or otherwise held in a data structure where there is a relationship between the members that can assist the search), then you *will* have to examine every member to find the right one.

The easiest solution is probably to sort it and then do a binary chop/search to find the element matching your criteria.

---

If you want efficiency with the ability to still take unsorted arrays, maintain a `sorted` flag somewhere for the array (i.e., turn the whole thing into a class containing the indicator and the array) that indicates that the list is sorted.

Then you set this flag to `false` whenever the array is changed.

At the point where you want to do your search, you first check the `sorted` flag and sort the array if it's set to `false` (setting it to `true` as part of that process). If the flag is `true`, just bypass the sort.

That way, you only sort when needed. If the array hasn't changed since the last sort, there's no point in re-sorting.

You can also maintain the original unsorted list if the user needs that, keeping the sorted list as an *additional* array withing the class (another advantage of class-ifying your array). That way, you lose nothing. You have the original untouched data for the user to get at, and a fast means of efficiently find your desired element.

Your object (when sorted) would then contain:

```
int[] lows       = {0,9,0,0,5,0,0,8,4,1,3,0,0,0,0};
int[] sortedlows = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,5,8,9};
boolean isSorted = true;
```

If you then changed `that_object[0]` to `3`, you'd end up with:

```
int[] lows       = {3,9,0,0,5,0,0,8,4,1,3,0,0,0,0};
int[] sortedlows = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,5,8,9};
boolean isSorted = false;
```

indicating that a sort would be needed before searching through `sortedLows`.

---

And keep in mind it's not a *requirement* to turn this into a class. If you're worried about it's performance (specifically accessing array elements through a getter method), you can maintain the arrays and flag yourself while still allowing direct access to the unsorted array. You just have to ensure that every place in your code that changes the array also sets the flag correctly.

But you should measure the performance before taking this path. The class-based way is "safer" since the object itself controls the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

First, normalise the data:

```
public static Dictionary<int, int> GetNormalised(int[] data)
{
    var normalised = data.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
        .GroupBy(p => p.value, p => p.index)
        .Where(p => p.Key != 0)
        .OrderBy(p => p.Key)
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Min());
    return normalised;
}
```

The search method:

```
public static int GetNearest(Dictionary<int, int> normalised, int value)
{
    var res = normalised.Where(p => p.Key <= value)
        .OrderBy(p => value - p.Key)
        .Select(p => (int?)p.Value)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (res == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", "Not found");
    }

    return res.Value;
}
```

The unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetNearestTest()
{
    var data = new[] { 0, 9, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 8, 4, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    var normalised = Program.GetNormalised(data);

    var value = 7;
    var expected = 4;
    var actual = Program_Accessor.GetNearest(normalised, value);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    value = 2;
    expected = 9;
    actual = Program_Accessor.GetNearest(normalised, value);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    value = 8;
    expected = 7;
    actual = Program_Accessor.GetNearest(normalised, value);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    value = 9;
    expected = 1;
    actual = Program_Accessor.GetNearest(normalised, value);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);        
}
```

To optimise the performance cache all the used results.

Comment: I like your solution, but unfortunately it is even slower

Answer (score 1):

To mock Java TreeSet in C#, use C# class: SortedDictionary or SortedSet; mock floor method in Java TreeSet, use LINQ method, to get minimum value.
SortedSet data = new SortedSet();
data.Where(p =>p < prices[i]).OrderByDescending(p=>p ).Take(1)

Based on HackerRank minimum cost algorithm, Java TreeSet implementation solution works fine, but C# SortedDictionary, SortedSet timeout.
Detail, see my coding blog: http://juliachencoding.blogspot.ca/2016/11/c-sorteddictionary-minimum-cost.html

So, C# SortedSet class GetViewBetween can do the same thing. See [GetViewBetween API](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/148727/123986)

There is a post: [SortedSet / SortedList with better LINQ performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675108/sortedset-sortedlist-with-better-linq-performance)