# SortedSet / SortedList with better LINQ performance?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-objects, sortedlist, sortedset

Let's say we have a sorted collection such as [SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) or [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) with many (10M+) elements. Lots of querying is happening, so performance matters. From runtime comparisons, I'm under the impression that LINQ to Objects doesn't take advantage of the sorting, therefore not taking advantage of potential performance gains.

First example - counting the elements in a range:

```
        var mySortedSet1 = new SortedSet<int>();
        // populate ...
        int rangeCount = (from n in mySortedSet1
                          where ((n >= 1000000000) && (n <= 2000000000))
                          select n).Count();
```

Not exactly sure what LINQ to Objects does here internally, worst case it's checking every single element which would be O(n). The can be done a lot faster by taking advantage of the sorting with a binary search for the lower and upper bound in O(log n).

Second example - SelectMany over list of sets:

```
        var myListOfSortedSets = new List<SortedSet<int>>();
        // populate...

        var q = myListOfSortedSets.SelectMany(s => s).OrderBy(s => s);
        foreach (var n in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
```

If LINQ to <strike>SQL</strike> Objects were to take advantage of the sorting, it could effectively zipper-merge all the sorted sets into one large sorted list in O(n). The .OrderBy on the result could then be ignored as the list is already sorted.

Instead, SelectMany concatenates all the sorted sets into one large (now unsorted) list which will required another O(n log n) sort. This can easily be verified by removing the .OrderBy and observing the order in which the elements are written to the console.

My question is: **is there already an alternative, more efficient implementation of LINQ to SortedSet/SortedList out there?**

[i4o](http://i4o.codeplex.com) looks very interesting, but it seems to require secondary index collections to improve query performance on the original collection. I just want queries on my sorted collections to run faster by taking advantage of the sorting.

Comment: The _Where_ method in Linq to object check each element. So there is no performance gain using _SortedList<>_ in this case.

Comment: What query do you exactly want to do? Because asserting "LINQ is stupid" is not really useful...

Comment: The examples above are very typical for the kind of queries I want to run. I'm sure there are more instances where LINQ to Objects could use  the sorting but doesn't, e.g. find min/max, so my question is if there's already a generic LINQ provider for sorted collections out there.

Comment: Nice question! I wonder how such a provider can be implemented. I'll investigate.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as stated, but since you're using a `SortedSet`, why not explicitly use the methods it provides instead of relying on LINQ to try to do the best thing? E.g., for your first example, `int rangeCount = mySortedSet1.GetViewBetween(1000000000, 2000000000).Count;` is always going to be faster, no matter how optimised LINQ is.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger Good point. For simple queries, that definitely makes sense. The scenario I have in mind involves more complex queries from multiple sources, with some sorted and non-sorted lists. Being able to use LINQ in a unified fashion across the board, without having to worry about optimization, would make things just a lot easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem for LINQ is that it can't know the sorted set is ordered exactly the same way as the query expects. Since any ordered collection can be created with an `IComparer` / `IComparable` / `Comparison<T>`, there is no knowing that `> 500000` actually makes sense. Maybe you've got a custom method on the comparer that first sorts by Odd/Even, then by number. In which case the order would be completely messed up and O(n) is required in all cases.

So to be on the safe side, LINQ will need to iterate through all elements in the Collection, even when it is sorted in some way. The default `.Where` implementation does not contain an optimization for ordered collections.

It might be possible to create an optimized version which keeps the existing ordering in mind while iterating, but it will be very difficult to do and to make it work in all cases.

You could create a `Between` method that uses the `GetViewBetween` method of `SortedSet` to return a new pre-ordered collection. Or would add the standard `.Where` as you'd normally would for any non-pre-sorted set.

Linq-to-SQL and Entity Framework make use if the IQueryable and will actually translate your Linq query to SQL and let the server handle the indexing, sorting, filtering etc.

Comment: Right, I meant "LINQ to Objects", not "LINQ to SQL".

Comment: Even if the `IComparer` problem could be solved, it would mean LINQ to objects would need `Expression`s, not just `Func` delegates.

Comment: It wouldn't as long as you'd be able to detect *which* `IComparer` is being used. Which would at least solve the 'default' sorting issues. Any custom sorting makes this whole topic an instant mess ;).