# Fastest C# collection for searching by property

Tags: c#, search, optimization, collections

I have the following simple class:

```
public class MyClass{
    public long StartRange { get; set; }
    public long EndRange { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I need to store many, 10^5 to 10^6, of these in a in-memory cache. There will be a single write to this cache at app start and many reads. This cache will be accessed in an ASP.NET environment, so many threads.

I need to lookup a row in this cache where my value is between StartRange and EndRange inclusive. The ranges do not overlap, but may be sparse. Simplest way I have found to do this is the following:

```
public MyClass Lookup(long value){
    return _set.FirstOrDefault(d => value >= d.StartRange && value <= d.EndRange);
}
```

I have tried this with storing the set as `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` and `SortedSet<T>`. The SortedSet is an order of magnitude faster. `HashSet<T>` is slightly faster than the SortedSet somehow. Any suggestions on the most efficient collection class to use or a better lookup would be most appreciated.

Comment: Try looking at [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx). It does a good job explaining how each collection class works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SortedSet / SortedList with better LINQ performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675108/sortedset-sortedlist-with-better-linq-performance)

Comment: Use a `struct` instead of a `class` (and make it immutable). 10^6 times ( 8 + 8 + 4 ) bytes is 20 MB, but with classes that would be twice as much. Then store them in a sorted array and use binary search, as answered below.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten: I'm having a hard time finding information about the space requirements for an object reference. Can you provide a citation for the "with classes that would be twice as much" part of your comment?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior The article on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx is quite old, and details may have changed (e.g. to support 64 bit), but take a look at the section titled "ObjectInstance". What it boils down to is this: objects on the heap have overhead for memory management and garbage collection, to support inheritance etc. structs do not have this overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The ranges do not overlap, but may be sparse.

If I'm understanding correctly, this means that if you sort them by StartRange, and then  identify the first item with `value >= d.StartRange`, you can immediately know that you've either found your item (if `value <= d.EndRange`), or there is no match, right?

So you can cut your time in half just by doing this:

```
public MyClass Lookup(long value){
    var candidate = _set.FirstOrDefault(d => value >= d.StartRange);
    if(candidate != null && value <= candidate.EndRange)
    {
        return candidate;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And, since searching in a sorted collection can easily be done in `O(log n)` time, you should be able to get significant performance gains with just a binary search. Here's some sample code that should get you on the right track.

```
List<MyClass> _set = new[]{
   new MyClass{StartRange = 18, EndRange = 18},
    new MyClass{StartRange = 10, EndRange = 15},
     new MyClass{StartRange = 20, EndRange = 21}
}.OrderBy(m => m.StartRange).ToList();

public class StartRangeComparer : IComparer<MyClass>
{
    public int Compare(MyClass first, MyClass second)
    {
        return first.StartRange.CompareTo(second.StartRange);
    }
}

StartRangeComparer startRangeComparer = new StartRangeComparer();

public MyClass Lookup(long value){
    var index = _set.BinarySearch(new MyClass{StartRange = value}, startRangeComparer);
    int candidateIndex = index >= 0 ? index : (~index) - 1;
    if(candidateIndex < 0)
    {
        // the given value is before any start-ranges in the list
        return null;
    }
    MyClass candidate = _set[candidateIndex];
    if(candidate.EndRange >= value)
    {
        return candidate;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you mean LastOrDefault for the sorted list. Please mention something about struct for future readers. Much appreciated.

Comment: @TheGwa: No, I'm pretty sure I meant `FirstOrDefault()`, because I want it to seek from the beginning until it finds one whose `StartRange` comes before (or equal to) the given value. Then I want it to short-circuit and avoid searching through the rest. And, regarding `struct`, the jury's still out on that one as far as I'm concerned. I haven't been able to track down enough information, or put together a good enough test, to be certain whether it's a good idea or not.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just sort by `StartRange`, use `Array.BinarySearch` to find the nearest one (that is still smaller) and because your ranges are sparse, know with one check (if `Endrange` is larger than x) if you found one or missed?
All you have to do for that to work is implement `IComparable<T>` with `StartRange` as key, which is easy.

Comment: You're on the right track, but it's not quite that easy. Unless you're looking for exactly the same `StartRange` value, the BinarySearch method won't help you find the "nearest one" will it?

Comment: Array.BinarySearch should return the closest match, with some bitmagic.(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Otherwise you have to implement your own BinSearch, which returns the closest one (that is very easy, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Might not be what you really need, but have you looked into NoSQL ? 
Some of the implementations act like what you want, and some have a cache that you can run from memory, so should be fast.

If my memory serves me Redis might be the one you'll want to look into. (here's an [article](https://redislabs.com/blog/taking-in-memory-nosql-to-the-next-level) about Redis).

K, some digging through my stuff yielded: [NoSQL DB comparisson](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis),  you can see there what are the major flavors and which use cases they are good for.

From what I've seen, they are using B-Trees for speed in some of the implementations. You might want to do something similar if you want to recreate the wheel I guess.

Comment: We have used this for other solutions. Couchbase in particular, but there is quite a lot of overhead for a very simple cache.

Comment: Absolutely agree, but was pointing out alternatives nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

If your ranges might overlap now or in the future, you might look into using an [*interval tree*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

But if your really sure your ranges have no overlaps, change your `class` to `struct` and do something like the following. The reason for changing `class` to `struct` is two-fold:

- Saves memory with an array. An array of reference types is an array of references to individual objects on the heap.
- Possibly more importantly, it helps preserve locality of reference. You  going to be jumping around in a contiguous block of memory rather than randomly all over the heap. That should help keep down paging.

Here's the code:

```
class MyClassMap
{
    MyClass[] backingStore ; // ordered by StartRange, then EndRange

    public MyClassMap( IEnumerable<MyClass> source )
    {
        backingStore.OrderBy( x => x.StartRange ).ThenBy( x => x.EndRange ) ;
    }

    public int? GetIdFromValue( long value )
    {
        int  lo = 0 ;
        int  hi = backingStore.Length ;
        int? ix = null ;
        while ( lo <= hi && !ix.HasValue )
        {
            int mid = lo + ((hi-lo)>>1) ;
            MyClass current = backingStore[mid] ;
            if      ( value > current.EndRange   ) { lo = mid+1      ; }
            else if ( value < current.StartRange ) { hi = mid-1      ; }
            else                                   { ix = current.Id ; }
        }

        return ix ;

    }

}
```